# How to wrap text around image in HTML/CSS like MS Word does it when choosing "Top and Bottom"

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm trying to implement the following text wrapping in HTML. I want the image to always appear below the first **line** of text, whatever the width of the page is.

Illustration:

[image]

And when the page is resized to be a bit narrower, it should look like this:

[image]

Basically the same way Word does it when you choose "Top and Bottom" in the image text wrapping options.

I'm pretty sure there's no built-in CSS feature for this layout. I think it could be implemented with text-measurements in JS - but it doesn't seem like a very elegant solution. 
Any ideas?

**Edit**

The solution should also work for placing the at the n-th line, not just the first line.

Comment: hope this will help you [link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/WD/wds4p6.html)

Comment: it would be ok if you knew in advance the height of your image? or the height of the image is dependent on the viewport width?

Comment: The height of the image does depend on the viewport width.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pvv3M/2/).

CSS

```
.bigdiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80%;
}
.picturediv {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.picturediv img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It does! But what do I do if I want the image to appear after the 2nd or 3rd line, etc.?

Comment: You'll have to experiment with the placement of the div. If it becomes complex, you'll probably have to resort to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted TimSPQR's answer to allow placing the image on any line.

This is achieved by adding a narrow div that floats above the image, the line-height of which controls how many lines of text appear before the image.

HTML:

```
<div class='bigdiv'>
Lorem 
<div class="clear">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class='picturediv'>
  <img src='http://www.hdpaperwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Mickey-Mouse-Wallpaper-disney-6628369-1024-768.jpg'/>
</div>    
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
```

CSS:

```
.bigdiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80%;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.picturediv {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.picturediv img {
    width: 100%;
}
.clear
{
    float: right;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvv3M/3/)